# In C, why do i need to return fahrenheit?

Tags: c, function, return

I have just started learning C and in a project from a book it gave me this code:

```
float fahrenheitFromcelcius (float celcius){
   float fahrenheit = celcius *1.8 +32.0;
   printf("%f celcius is %f fahrenheit\n", celcius , fahrenheit);
   return fahrenheit;
}
```

Why do i need to return fahrenheit. I thought you return it to check if everything went ok or to stop the function

Comment: Because the point of the function is to get the value of Fahrenheit for a given Celsius temperature? Sometimes you want to actually use the data returned from a function, write it to the screen, maybe. If you just returned nothing, the data would be lost.

Comment: There are to an extent two classes of function return values. In one case, the function returns success or failure (possibly with various failure codes). In another, it returns a value and failure is not a possibility, or is indicated by some other mechanism.  Lastly, there are hybrid return values. For example, with an `int` function, a positive value might be a result, 0 that nothing was done, and negative values various types of failure. As floating point values are not necessarily exact, it's somewhat awkward to have a `float` function return failure codes - so it is probably a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The posted code snippet is what is called a "function".  You can think of this function as a celsius-to-fahrenheit machine.

You feed the machine a float value (referred to in the function as `celsius`).  The machine does some calculations, and it spits back out a float value called `fahrenheit`.

Actual usage of this function would look like this:

```
float tempInCelsius = 0.0;
float tempInFahrenheit = fahrenheitFromCelcius(tempInCelsius);
```

When that second line is execute, we're calling the `fahrenheitFromCelcius` function.  Calculations are done on the value we passed in (`tempInCelsius`, which to the function, is simply known as `celsius`).  After the calculations are done, the function "returns" the calculated value and assigns it to our variable, `tempInFahrenheit`.

Comment: Adding to this, normally your function would not print anything. I think OP is confused because his goal was to print the result so he wonders why it then needs to be returned also, since the goal has been reached.  The answer is that it's a better design for the function to just do one thing; the conversion; and then the caller can decide whether to print it out or take some other action.